# Best PHP timezone list

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I have looked over the PHP list of [supported timezones](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php), but the whole list is a little long to include in a drop-down menu, for the user to select his or her timezone. Is there a list with the main city/area on that can be used?

My geography is terrible and add that to not knowing all the area and which timezone they fall into it could be a long day to construct the list my self!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you consider the main city/area?

Comment: If you feel a list is too long for a drop-down menu (which I would rarely agree with, since it is easy to use the keyboard to jump to a place in the list), you could consider an autocomplete widget.

Comment: I just think having every one of the timezones in the list is a little overkill isn't it?

Comment: @Ben James: Some people don't even know they can browse a select list with their keyboard. I partially agree with here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
[Timezone Dropdown Select List](http://www.michaelapproved.com/articles/timezone-dropdown-select-list/)

Comment: I think that it is a good solution, as timezones never change and the users usually know what the timezone is where they live.

Comment: This is a mistake, since there are both half-hour timezones and also DST.

Answer (score 0):

Group the locations by timezone which you can do programmatically.

Comment: You mean group by UTC offset? The problem is timezones also have DST rules (which change even between timezones with the same non-DST UTC offset).

Comment: @Alix Axel True but its good enough for this question. The accepted answer above does not even answer the question and the comments at the top.